# Im Trying to Detect a Certain Key being Pressed (Python)

Tags: python, key, detect

This is My Code, I'm a beginner and I've been looking around I've looked at least 5-10 posts about this, they aren't really helping me because I can't understand the code.

In My code im trying a really basic starting screen for a game and what I want to do is how detect E or S being pressed at the time of the start screen,

```
print (" _____________________________________________ ")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|          The Chronicles                    |")
print ("|                Of Game                      |")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|_____________________________________________|")
print ("|                                             |")
print ("|       START             EXIT                |")
print ("|        (S)               (E)                |")
print (" \___________________________________________/ ")
```

Comment: This is OS dependent, so say which OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I use getch, if you want to use, download py-getch:

https://github.com/joeyespo/py-getch

the command to install: python setup.py install

Example code:

```
from getch import getch, pause

# game loop
while(True):
    key = getch()
    if(key == 'S'):
        print('key S pressed...')
    elif(key == 'E'):
        print('key E pressed...')
```

[image: key pressed]

Comment: Thanks im going to try this one out

Comment: I tried this, and it works. However, it breaks the terminal. So I have to do a reset to get everything back. Moreover, when using try it does not catch `except KeyboardInterrupt`.